# How to hide grouped series Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highcharts and I have lots of series grouped.

ex : 
A & B |
C & D |
E & F |
...

On the chart legend, I'm only displaying A, C , E ... and when the user click on one of them, it only hides A or C or E and the grouped serie is not hidden.

Is there a property that I missed?

Comment: You can link one series to another with linkedTo property http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.linkedTo

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve We can't help you without seeing what you've got.

Comment: @morganfree , can you put linkedTo as the answer, you're a F genius ^^. (I wanna give you the credit instead of writting myself the answer)

Comment: @jlbriggs , the problem with the code I have is that I can't show a "bit" of it, if someone wants to fully understand, I need to put all of it, that's why I use an example that recaps my problem instead.

Comment: why do people downvote answer solved questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Series.linkedTo](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.linkedTo) property you can link one series to another - so they will be hidden simultaneously.

```
series: [{
    ...
}, {
    linkedTo: ':previous',
    ...
}]
```